# I am curious why this question was deleted

Tags: discussion

https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6554/diy-morse-code-telegraph-using-only-basic-components

only reference still on this site is the edit-record of my answer: https://ham.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4787

I am just trying to understand what criteria were used to determine that deletion was the correct moderation action.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted that question, and I'm sorry it means your answer went with it.

This is how I made the decision:

- The author wanted it deleted. Ordinarily, this doesn't outweigh it getting a satisfactory answer, but:
- It did not seem all that great a question.
- Your answer did not actually address the better parts of the question:

  - The question was asking for a *canonical* circuit;
  - it was asking for a receiver of similar design to go with the transmitter;
  - and your answer mentioned CW up front but then described a scheme to produce **MCW** output without explaining the difference.

---

In general, users can see their own deleted posts, but I'm not sure whether this applies to an answer to *someone else's* deleted question. (I found ambiguous information on Meta Stack Exchange). In any case, here's the text of your answer in case you or anyone wants it:

```
So, CW transmitter is basically an carrier-wave (AM) transmitter. After all, "CW" stands for "Continuous Wave"

Example:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Now, where it shows "Audio IN" you can just feed in a sine wave, say 500 Hz.

That is as simple it can get... you can search on the internet for AM receivers with discrete components, many very simple circuit diagrams are available.

[source of diagram](http://www.circuitstoday.com/long-range-am-transmitter)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dFYq.jpg
```

Comment: fair enough... that satisfies my curiosity. thanks